How to reveal current file in XCode on the "Test Navigator" panel?
When I'm working with tests I want to find my class in the Test Navigator list.
(Not in the project navigator, which is done by pulling down the menu with a right click or by keyboard with Shift+Cmd+J)
It's quite cumbersome when you have a lot of test files and you want to test a single specific test.
Is there a shortcut or option in the menu for that?
